# Is it efficient to use IN clause for 1000 different values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In my Java program, I need to select 1000 rows from a MySQL db with different `WHERE` condition for each row. Those rows must be retrieved with one single query. To do so, I have used `IN` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE (columnA,columnB) IN ((valA1,valB1),(valA2,valB2),(valA3,valB3),...)
```

which searches for rows where `columnA=valA1 AND columnB=valB1` OR `columnA=valA2 AND columnB=valB2` and so on.

Is this approach efficient to be applied for 1000 rows (means 1000 pairs of (valA,valB))? I have been looking for an efficient way for `bulk select` and this approach is what I have been able to find so far.

Comment: The best way to find an answer is to create some random test data and try it out. If it is efficient enough for your use case, you are fine - otherwise you can use the same test data to try out other approaches and tune the query.

Comment: @AndreasFester thanks for you answer. but I think your comment doesn't make sense in stackoverflow community. we are here to share our experiences, otherwise we could devote a lot of time for each problem and find the final answer on our own!

Comment: Maybe storing this criteria array in temporary engine=memory indexed table will improve.

Comment: @soheil That is actually what I did - sharing my experience. How shall we know whether your approach is "efficient" enough for you if we do not know any metrics? Depending on your use case, a query which runs for two hours might still be fine, another use case might require the query to take only a few milliseconds.

Comment: @AndreasFester I mean others might have already tried to experiment what approach is more efficient `in comparison to other possible approaches` for this specific problem. then this problem would have a recognized efficient solution.

Comment: I removed the java and jdbc tag, because your problem seems to be confined to MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Is this efficient?  That depends on factors that you haven't explained in the question.

But . . . if you have an index on `(columnA, columnB)` and all the values in the `IN` clause are constants, then [MySQL should take advantage of the index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#row-constructor-range-optimization).  This is newish functionality available in MySQL 8+.

MySQL has another optimization for constant values in an `IN` list.  It sorts them and uses a binary search.  A table scan is still needed, but the binary search makes the comparisons much faster. I do not know if MySQL has expanded this to handle tuples as well as constants.  Given the increased focus on tuple optimization, I would not be surprised if MySQL does this optimization as well.